# Больше одной галереи на одной странице

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, не силён в jquery, использую плагин фансибокс + зум увиличения, вопрос, как заставить работать этот [плагин](http://jsfiddle.net/hbUh8/)  учитывая что на странице могут быть несколько таких галерей которые генерятся через цикл и могут быть 15 и 20 галерей,

Comment: в чем собственно проблема ? вы пробовали просто добавить вторую галерею ? сдается мне что нет http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/hbUh8/2/

Comment: Конечно пробовал, а вы проверяли что получилось? : ) По клацайте там, поймете.

Comment: http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples вот тут несколько галерей, посмотрите как сделано. я думаю они id меняют.

Comment: у них там в числовом порядке от #zoom_1 до #zoom_10, на каждую галерею прописан скрипт, а у меня они будут генерироваться в цикле в неизвестном кол-ве, возможно ли сделать скрипт один универсальный который будет поддерживать множество галерей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

перебираем все .zoom_03, галерею берем как next(), видимо это ограничение  плагина, что туда надо именно id вставлять, иначе вообще красиво сделать можно было-бы (без того чтобы при генерации страницы id приделывать к галерее)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".zoom_03").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var galery = $this.next().attr('id');        
        $this.elevateZoom({
            gallery: galery,
            cursor: 'pointer'
        })
    });

    $(".zoom_03").bind("click", function (e) {
        var ez = $(this).data('elevateZoom');
        $.fancybox(ez.getGalleryList());
        return false;
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/hbUh8/3/